# Unplugging iPad/iPhone Charger: Which end to unplug first?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging, charger, charge

After charging an iPad or iPhone, which end do you unplug first: the one that's connected in the device or the charger end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't any difference, there is no chance of anything bad happening regardless, although if you were particularly worried about this sort of thing, then frankly you would be better to turn the charger unit off at the wall socket first, after which it is utterly irrelevant (assuming you are using a wall charger).  If you are charging from a PC with no option to turn off the USB port as such, then you might have a preference depending on if you leave the cable in or not etc, but it's just that; a preference.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter, either way is fine.

Answer (score 1):

At all, it really won't matter. But I always disconnect the charger end first. This is done to prevent harm in the charger, but with modern chargers there shouldn't be such problems...

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter. You could unplug the wall charger first and then that has already turned everything else off.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the wall charger first, then from the phone. This way there is no power in the cord and no damage can be done to the cord if the phone end comes in contact with the cord.